# C++ condition_variable wait_for not always working

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2017, mutex, condition-variable

My application start the `logThread` thread and then cyclically calls `lookForSms` which makes a curl call and wait for `logThread` to read a certain string, but this string may never come so i used a `condition_variable` `wait_for` so that eventually (after 5 minutes) it can continue the test.
The problem is at times it waits a lot longer, sometimes 20 min sometimes forever.
How can I make it reliably work?

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017, here the code:

```
            void lookForSms(CURL *curl) {
                sms_found = false;
            
                int  i;
                CURLcode res;
                cout << "\n" << timestamp() << "\t";
            
                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                if (res == CURLE_OK) {
                    unique_lock<mutex> lk(F);
            
                    analysis << timestampMil() << "\t";
            
                    while (cv.wait_for(lk, TIMEOUT_SMS * 1000ms) != cv_status::timeout && !sms_found);
            
                    if (sms_found) {
                        analysis << timestampMil() << "\tSMS RECEIVED\n";
                        cout << "\tOK";
                    }
                    else {
                        analysis << timestampMil() << "\tSMS LOST\n";
                        cout << "\tKO";
                    }
            
                }
            }

            void logThread() {
                string line;
                int n, i, count;
                unsigned char buf[BUFFER];
                while (!close) {
                    N.lock();
                    M.lock();
                    N.unlock();
            
                    n = RS232_PollComport(comport, buf, BUFFER);
                    if (n > 0 && n < BUFFER) {
                        buf[n] = '\0';
            
                        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                            if (buf[i] == '\n') {
                                all << timestampMil() << "\t" << line << "\n";
                                handleLine(line);
                                line = string();
                            }
                            else if (buf[i] != '\r' && buf[i] >= 32) {
                                line += buf[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    M.unlock();
                }
            
            }

            void handleLine(string line) {
                if (searchString(line, RCV_SMS)) {
                    unique_lock<mutex> lk(F);
                    sms_found = true;
                    lk.unlock();
                    cv.notify_all();
                }
            }
```

---

[EDIT] This should have everything it needs to recreate the problem.

```
            #include <iostream>
            #include <thread>
            #include <mutex>
            #include <condition_variable>

            #define TIMEOUT_SMS 300
            #define DELAY_SMS 10

            
            mutex L, M, N, F;
            condition_variable cv;

            void logThread() {
                while (!close) {
                    N.lock();
                    M.lock();
                    N.unlock();

                    handleLine("");
                    Sleep(500);

                    M.unlock();
                }

            }


            void lookForSms() {

                    unique_lock<mutex> lk(F);
                    sms_found = false;
                    unlocked = false;


                    //while (cv.wait_for(lk, TIMEOUT_SMS * 1000ms) != cv_status::timeout && !unlocked);
                    cv.wait_for(lk, 10 * TIMEOUT_SMS * 1000ms, []() {return unlocked; });

                    if (sms_found) {
                        cout << "\tOK";
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "\tKO";
                    }

                }
            }

            void handleLine(string line) {
                if (false) {// the problem is when cv remains locked
                    unique_lock<mutex> lk(F);
                    unlocked = true;
                    sms_found = true;
                    lk.unlock();
                    cv.notify_all();
                }
            }

            void stopThreads() {
                N.lock();
                M.lock();
                //stop log thread
                close = true;
                N.unlock();
                M.unlock();
            }

            int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


                thread logger(logThread);

                for (i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
                    lookForSms();
                    Sleep(DELAY_SMS * 1000);
                }

                //aquire mutex and set close to true, then join
                stopThreads();
                //wait for the thread to end
                logger.join();

                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Spurious wakes could accumulate.  What is the definition of TIMEOUT_SMS?

Comment: I think we really need a [mcve]. I do notice that if there's any reason why the `wait_for` ends but `sms_found` is not set then it goes into another 5 second wait. That is if elsewhere in the code `F.notify_all()` is called that could result in prolonged waiting. But I can't see a risk of that in the code presented. The remedy would be to use `wait_until()` or the predicate version. Spurious wakes could cause that too but on most platforms they're rare but you are vulnerable.

Comment: @John `#define TIMEOUT_SMS  300`. @Persixty I have only the main and `logThread` threads, and only the latter calls `cv.notify_all();`

Comment: @Persixty, `wait_until` is the same unreliable. They both would go through the function without time-out.